Updating cache with an entity with a version field
I'm using Hibernate with a version column in my entity class to implement optimistic concurrency control.
Right now I'm implementing redis-caching.
I would like to update the cache just when I .save() my updated entity in DB.
The problem is that .save() method in JPA returns the object without incrementing the version field, so the cache becomes outdated.
Of course, I can manually increment the version field right after .save(), but it doesn't sound like a good solution at all.
Therefore, is there any solution for such situations?
I've also tried .saveAndFlush() method.

evict it and load again.

If Hibernate is not incrementing the version field then it is probably not correctly annotated. Check it please.

Whenever an Entity gets saved, updated or delete, evict all the cache by the key.  When getting by id or getting all, cache them all by the key.

Save itself does not ensure it is in the database when it returns. It is the transaction commit that makes the changes in the database; JPA/Hibernate will increment the version just before that point. You should make sure you are not relying on Save directly and instead hook into the transaction boundary or use a callback event so that you are sure the transaction has committed before updating external caches or your cache will be wrong if there is a rollback
